# Multiple models in a single get_queryset() to populate data in a template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to push multiple data sets into a template, home.html, using class based views.  I don't know if this is the right way or if there is a better way to do this.

views.py

```
class HomePage(ListView):
   template_name = 'home.html'
   context_object_name = 'result'

   def get_queryset(self):
      query1 = {}
      query2 = {}
      query3 = {}
      query1['url'] = table1.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username'])
      query2['text'] = table2.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username'])
      query3['link'] = table3.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username'])
      return (query1, query2, query3)
```

home.html

```
{% for query1_data in result %}
   {% if query1_data.url %}
       <img src="{{query1_data.url}}">
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for query2_data in result %}
   {% if query2_data.text %}
       ...
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It works but it seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: And why do you **need** to do this? Likely your models are not well designed. I would suggest redesigning your models.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat This was just an example.  I have a template with different sections pulling data from different tables. Are you saying, I should redesign my model to pull all the data from 3 tables and output to a single result?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `TemplateView` instead:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
   
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        result = {
            'table1': Table1.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username']),
            'table2': Table2.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username']),
            'table3': Table3.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username']),
        }
       return result
```

Then you can iterate over them in your template like so:

```
{% for object in table1 %}
    <img src="{{ object.url }}">
{% endfor %}

{% for object in table2 %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Also, please use *Pascal Casing* (capitalized) for class names :)

Comment: This is simpler than mine.  What should I do if I have different filter for each table?

Comment: @user15364819 Sorry, I didn't realize that was a requirement.  I've made an update with that in mind.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this approach. Simple and clear.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePage(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'home.html'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      ctx.update({
         'urls' : table1.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username']),
         'texts': table2.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username']),
         'links': table3.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username'])
      })
      return ctx
```

In your template

```
{% for url in urls %}
    <img src="{{url.url}}">
{% endfor %}

{% for text in texts %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I like this.  I'll try this and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked!  I had to change "View" to "TemplateView" to make it work.  I was getting errors if I use "View"

Comment: @user15364819 Great! I'm glad I could help.